# Insert into a table using average value of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table A with 2 columns

```
Time  Value
9:00   10
9:05   15
9:10   12
.
.
.
9:55   7
10:00  12
```

I want to use the above tables and insert into Table B as if

```
Time  Value

9:00   xyz
9:05   xyz1
```

where xyz is average of (9:00 to 9:55)
xyz1 is average of (9:05 to 10:00)

Once 10:05 entry comes to Table A, then similarly one more entry of Time: 9:10 will be created in Table B

Can someone help me with the SQL INSERT query for Table B, assuming we have Table A's data and when new entry comes to Table A, we have the script which is writing to Table A, but we need the INSERT query accordingly for Table B..

I hope the issue is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO B (Time, Value) VALUES(SELECT Time, AVG(Value) FROM A WHERE Time  BETWEEN Time AND DATE_ADD(Time, interval 55 minutes))
```

This will return a single record you need to run it in a loop or multiple times with varying Starting `Time` value.